# Network graph looks different in PNG and PDF using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, sna, ggally

I have a weighted undirect graph as an igraph object :

```
IGRAPH 7d6665b UNW- 168 2345 -- 
 + attr: name (v/c), label (v/c), degree_alpha (v/n)
 + edges from 7d6665b (vertex names):
[1] 7 --13 7 --15 13--15 11--16 15--17 6 --18 15--20 6 --25 18--25 6 --28 10--28 15--28 18--28 20--28 25--28 23--30 15--31
[18] 17--31 28--31 6 --33 17--33 18--33 25--33 28--33 7 --34 13--34 15--34 16--35 15--37 18--37 20--37 25--37 28--37 13--43
+ ... omitted several edges
```

I use the function [ggnet2](https://briatte.github.io/ggnet/) (part of GGally) to plot my igraph object as a ggplot2 object :

```
ggnet2(graph,
   node.size = V(graph)$degree_alpha,
   edge.label = NULL,
   edge.size = E(graph)$weight/3,
   node.label =  NULL,
   color = "#038e9a",
   alpha = 0.75,
   edge.color = "#6E6E6E",
   legend.size = 0) + guides(color = FALSE, size = FALSE)
```

When I export to PNG, or just the preview given by RStudio, it looks like this :

[image: png export of the graph]

When I export to PDF, I have a different output, with thicker edges :

[image]

You can find the graph object in RDS format [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yogpd3iv4llc42i/graph.rds?dl=0). How can I make my PDF export looks the same as the PNG one ? What does explain the difference in the first place ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @tvg sorry if this wat not clear : I don't understand why my graph is so different in a PDF format. This is an issue because I need it in PDF, but for now the export transforms the appearance of my graph.

Comment: I don't have a great answer to this other than that I have seen this before myself and  assume that the default graphical parameters for png and pdf are different so relative sizes appear different.  The obvious thing is to tweak the node.size and edge.size parameters to make these smaller in pdf.  But if someone out there knows how to 'translate' png into pdf to get identical appearance I would be very interested myself.  I guess you could set all the size parameters to scale to a value that incorporates the behavior of the png and pdf devices but I don't know how to do this.